# c# linq - get elements from array which do not exist in a different array

Tags: c#, linq

I have two arrays idxListResponse & _index both of which have the same structure.

Each of these arrays contains a number of elements with different properties one of which is a child array called indexdata

Each element of this array has a number of properties one of which is another array called datafield. This has a number of key value pair properties.

So in essence I have a hierarchy of 3 separate arrays.

I'm looking to get the first level of the hierarchy + all elements of the 2nd level where the 3rd level items don't match, i.e. exclude only those items from the 2nd level where the 3rd level items are a match.

I've tried approaching this a number of different ways but so far I'm not getting anywhere, could anyone help.

FYI - here's my latest attempt

```
var q = idxListResponse.Index.Where(a =>
    a.IndexData.All(b =>
        b.DataField.All(c =>
            _index.Index.Where(z =>
                z.IndexData.All(y => y.DataField.Contains(c.name))
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) is a good way of doing that:

```
var items = source1.Except(source2);
```

Would return all items in `source1` *except* those in `source2`.

Since your collections appear to be different types, you would do something like:

```
source1.Except(source2.Select(s => /* selector here */))
```

Or you could create your own implementation of `IEqualityComparer` and use that to compare the two different types.

Comment: thanks but just can't get that working. The issue is that if 1 of the properties of an element in the 3rd array matches then that seems to be getting dropped. I need all the properties for each element in the third array to match a corresponding entry before it can be removed