# Find the number that don't exist in another array

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find the values in array A that don't exist in array B

```
A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

B = {1,2,3,7,8}

result = {4,5,6,9,10}
```

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801757/disjoint-union-in-linq

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975969/c-sharp-linq-get-elements-from-array-which-do-not-exist-in-a-different-array

Comment: All of answers is correct vote to who one?

Comment: @puria Typically, highest voted or first-in wins. Whichever you found most helpful to your needs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
  var C = A.Except(B);
```

or, if you want it as an array:

```
  int[] C = A.Except(B).ToArray();
```

Comment: dang you beat me by a few seconds!

Comment: Dont think its an LOL situation  -  legit question... plus, will help new comers and others who weren't aware.  After all, this is what the site is for.

Answer (score 5):

```
var arrayA = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

var arrayB = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8 };

var result = arrayA.Except(arrayB);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Linq52() 
{ 
    int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 }; 
    int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 }; 

    IEnumerable<int> aOnlyNumbers = numbersA.Except(numbersB); 

    Console.WriteLine("Numbers in first array but not second array:"); 
    foreach (var n in aOnlyNumbers) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(n); 
    } 
}
```